# Change opacity on child element in CSS

Tags: html, css, opacity

I am trying to change the opacity of a child element (button) within a form to opacity: 1;

The parent form is at opacity: 0.6; and I can't figure out how to override this.

Comment: Give an ID/class to the button and use that to select it (`#id` or `.class`). Then set `opacity: 1;`.

Comment: Add `opacity: 1` to the button. This should override the opacity of 0.6 inherited from the parent element (the form).

Answer (score 1):

To have child with `opacity: 1`, [you need to use the `background` property, as `opacity` is applied to the element as a whole, including the children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4a/06/52/4a065201509c0fc50e7341ce04cf7902.jpg");
}

form {
  padding: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

form button {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't override it by using `!important` or by simply adding a CSS `opacity:1;` to the button object since is a child and is part of the rendered content of the parent.

But you can override it probably by using JS or easier than that by using the css `:not(X)` pseudo-class selector, where X is the "object" , "id" or "class" of your choosing.

for example:

```css
.parent :not(button) {
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>some text here or other content than just a button </h1>
    <div>some text here or other content than just a button </div>
    <p>some text here or other content than just a button </p>
    <button> im going to have my own opacity</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the form `opacity: 1;` and make everything inside it except the button `opacity: 0.6;`.

You could do this by labelling everything in the form except the button with a `class`, and set this to `opacity: 0.6;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all items in the form which are not a `<button>` to have an opacity of 0.6.

```css
form :not(button) {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <label for="fname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```